# Dataflow logs from Stackdriver charges

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Dataflow is already integrated with stackdriver.but in terms of charges does it cost separtly for dataflow_steps stackdriver logs.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please take your time to read what questions you can ask here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ... you aren't asking anything, you just make a statement

Answer (score 1):

The Stackdriver logs are priced separately and does not come under the dataflow pricing. You can check for the pricing details here - https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#logging-costs